# Change of variable in complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

When I want to evaluate the following integral 
$$\int_\Gamma e^{-z^2}dz~~~~~~~~~~~\Gamma:|z|=R,0\leq\arg{z}<\frac{\pi}{4}$$
so I subtitude, letting(choose a single-valued analytic branch)
$$z=w^{\frac{1}{8}}, ~dz=\frac{1}{8}w^{\frac{1}{8}-1}dw$$
the integral change to
$$\frac{1}{8}\int_{|w|=R^8}\frac{w^{\frac{1}{8}}e^{-w^{\frac{1}{4}}}}{w}dw$$
and according to Cauchy's integral formula
$$\frac{1}{8}\int_{|w|=R^8}\frac{w^{\frac{1}{8}}e^{-w^{\frac{1}{4}}}}{w}dw
=2\pi i\times\frac{1}{8}w^{\frac{1}{8}}e^{-w^{\frac{1}{4}}}|_{w=0}=0$$
Apparently, the solution is unreasonable. But what is wrong?

Comment: Your substitution should be $z=Re^{i\theta}$, so that $dz=Rie^{i\theta}d\theta$, and $0\leq \theta< \pi/4$. We make this substitution because the substitution describes the path $\Gamma$ which you give.

Comment: "But what is wrong?" Your function $g(w) = w^{1/8}e^{-w^{1/4}}$ is not holomorphic in the region enclosed by the contour. It has a branch point at $0$, and you must pick a branch-cut from $0$ to $\infty$ to get a domain on which a holomorphic branch exists. Since it is not holomorphic, the integral formula doesn't apply.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer ，You mean the substitution is right and just the Cauchy's integral formula is not applicable?

Comment: Sort of. The substitution is not incorrect, but I don't think it is helpful either. I don't know if there is a closed form for the integral. Maybe numeric integration is the best one can do.